# Phaser game in Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phaser-framework

I have a phaser game that I want to kinda implement in a ionic app. My ideia is to run the phaser game from a external link and create a button inside the ionic app that links to the game and launches from the InAppBrowser or the Cordova web view as explained [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/).

I have no problems running the phaser game in the mobile browser (chrome), but when it launches from the app with either the InAppBrowser or the Cordova web view the game is small.

Also, I can't click on the buttons.

Any ideia what the problem might be? In the phaser game, or in the app...

It runs well in the browser.

Link to the game: [works on firefox and on mobile](http://spinner-ecgm.esy.es/).

```
(function() {
   var game = new Phaser.Game(JOGO.area.width, JOGO.area.height, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game');     

           // -- gamestates
           game.state.add('loading', JOGO.loading);
           game.state.add('preload', JOGO.preload);
           game.state.add('menu', JOGO.menu);
           game.state.add('levelSelect', JOGO.levelSelect);
           game.state.add('jogo', JOGO.jogo);
           game.state.add('fim', JOGO.fim);

           game.state.start('loading');
})();
```

**Play button:**

```
var jogar = this.game.add.button(this.game.width / 2, this.game.height - this.game.height/4, "jogar");
        jogar.anchor.set(0.5);
        menuGroup.add(jogar);
        jogar.state = "levelSelect";
        jogar.events.onInputDown.add(this.onSpriteDown, this);
        jogar.events.onInputOver.add(this.onSpriteOver, this);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

When I first loaded the game in the browser It gave me an error in menu.js here:

```
onSpriteOver : function (sprite, pointer) {
    JOGO.somButton.play(); //Error on this line!!!!!
    var xpos = sprite.x;
    if(!animate)
    var tween = this.game.add.tween(sprite)
            .to({ x: xpos + 6 }, 100, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None)
            .to({ x: xpos - 5 }, 100, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None)
            .to({ x: xpos + 4 }, 100, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None)
            .to({ x: xpos - 3 }, 100, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None)
            .to({ x: xpos }, 100, Phaser.Easing.Linear.None)
            .start();
},
```

I think somButton was undefined. I reloaded and it work OK in the browser and on mobile. It doesn't always give the error. It only had the error on first load in the browser and on mobile.

**Original**

Does your phaser game have a fixed width and height or does it fill the viewport like this:

```
game = new Phaser.Game(window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio, window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio, Phaser.CANVAS, 'gameArea');
```

This is taken from here:

https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-scale-a-game-for-all-device-sizes-in-phaser/

Comment: Edited the post with more code, i have this: `var game = new Phaser.Game(JOGO.area.width, JOGO.area.height, Phaser.CANVAS, 'game');`

Comment: What I am getting at is that your device pixel density may be very high and this will cause your game to scale down. If you browse through the article I linked to it explains it better. Thats why in the code I referenced it takes the window.innerWidth and height and multiplies it by the devicePixelRatio.

Comment: I managed to scale it, but the thing is that the buttons also doesn't work.

Comment: Could you share some more code. How are the buttons initialised? Maybe link to the game in the browser?

Comment: Hum, so the problem might be on its first load. Probably that's why it doesnt load properly in the app. thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Yeah, check the console for any errors. Like I say on first load somButton is not defined.